# codeigniter call to a member function row() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter

I've searched the ends of the earth and back for this solution, and for everyone else, the fix was to autoload the database class in autoload.php. However, I am already doing this, so I don't know where else to go with it.

Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

function validate_credentials(){
    $this->load->model('membership_model');

    // call the member function from membership_model.php
    $q = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($q){
        // user info is valid
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('site/members_area');

    }else{
        $this->index();
    }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Membership_model extends CI_Model{

function validate(){
    // this method is called from the login.php controller
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $q = $this->db->get('members');


    if($q->num_rows == 1){

        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Any help on this please, I'm going round in circles with this

My next thought is that php.ini needs configuring on my host server, to load the mysql modules - but I would very surprised by this?

Just to clarify - the line:

```
if($q->num_rows)
```

Is the problem, saying that I am trying to reference a property of a non object

Answer (score 2):

Actually

```
if($q->num_rows)
```

should be

```
if($q->num_rows()) // It returns the number of rows returned by the query.
```

So you can use

```
if($q->num_rows()) // In this case it'll be evaluated true if rows grater than 0 
{
    // code when rows returned
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed this, and I still get:

Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /home/classify/public_html/songbin/application/models/membership_model.php on line 18

If I edit database.php to be
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
Instead of 
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

The error message disappears, but the query still fails to return anything. The db info is definately there.

Consequently, I have another function to insert data into the db, which also fails to actually insert

Answer (score 1):

num_rows is a function.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

}
```

So you need

```
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I hadn't assigned a User to the database, therefore couldn't access it.

Relief